# Function that gives 1 if input is positive or 0, and gives 0 if input is negative

Tags: functions

I'm writing a research paper where I came to the need of defining a function that gives +1 for all integer inputs which are positive or 0, and gives 0 for all negative inputs.

I tried to look for some solutions here and some where else but i couldn't find a similar problem. Can someone here please give me some suggestions. Thank you guys

Comment: For nonzero integers (also nonzero real numbers) , you can use $\frac{sgn(x)+1}{2}$

Comment: @Peter That's a great function! Thank you!

Comment: I would be pleased if I could receive more suggestions.

Comment: If you take "ceil" of this expression, it also gives the desired result for $0$.

Comment: The title is a perfectly fine definition.

Answer (score 2):

The trivial answer is to define it piecewise:

$$ f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 \quad \text{if} \quad x\ge0\\
0 \quad \text{if} \quad x<0\\
\end{cases}$$